# How to add data from Npgsql(Postgres) to specific columns of Data grid view in window forms in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql, winforms, npgsql

I have been trying to add data fetched from Postgres using Npgsql and store the data in pre-defined columns of data grid view. I have tried this. First Time it works fine but second time it causes it the data grid view to remove the old columns and create new columns with the name of the columns in table in database.
I'm new to C# and windows forms but I can't figure this out.

```
public static void GetUsers(DataGridView GVObj, DataGridViewColumn User_Name_GVC,
            DataGridViewColumn User_UserName_GVC,DataGridViewColumn User_Password_GVC, 
            DataGridViewColumn User_PhoneNumber_GVC, DataGridViewColumn User_Address_GVC,
            DataGridViewColumn User_RoleID_GVC, DataGridViewColumn User_UserID_GVC)
        {
            try
            {
                SQLqUery = "SELECT * FROM users;";
                CMD = new NpgsqlCommand(SQLqUery, Main.DbConnection);
                Main.DbConnection.Open();

                NpgsqlDataAdapter DA = new NpgsqlDataAdapter(CMD);
                dt = new DataTable();
                //CMD.ExecuteReader();
                dt.Load(CMD.ExecuteReader());
                //DA.Fill(dt);
                Main.DbConnection.Close();

                GVObj.DataSource = null;
                //------Columns of The DataGridView
                User_UserName_GVC.DataPropertyName = dt.Columns["UserName"].ToString();
                User_Password_GVC.DataPropertyName = dt.Columns["Password"].ToString();
                User_PhoneNumber_GVC.DataPropertyName = dt.Columns["PhoneNumber"].ToString();
                User_Address_GVC.DataPropertyName = dt.Columns["Address"].ToString();
                User_RoleID_GVC.DataPropertyName = dt.Columns["RoleFK"].ToString();
                User_UserID_GVC.DataPropertyName = dt.Columns["UserId"].ToString();
                User_Name_GVC.DataPropertyName = dt.Columns["Name"].ToString();
                //Columns of The DataGridView------
                GVObj.DataSource = dt;

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Main.DbConnection.Close();
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error");
            }
        }
```

Comment: i guess the `DataGridViewColumn User_Name_GVC` parameter duplicated inside `public static void GetUsers(.....)` method

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fixe the issue by giving "dataPropertyName" to each data grid view column and by setting GVObj.AutoGenerateColumns = false